# Error in my join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with the code below but it is returning an error -

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

I expect the query to create a table using the data from existing tables.

```
create table Allactivity as
(
    select dbo.dim_client.*,dbo.dim_transaction.* 
    from dbo.dim_client,dbo.dim_transaction,dbo.fact_capital   
    where dbo.dim_client.dim_client_key=dbo.fact_capital.dim_client_key
        and dbo.dim_transaction.dim_transaction_key=dbo.fact_capital.dim_transaction_key
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using Microsoft SQL Server. T-SQL has a different syntax: `SELECT INTO:`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx

```
select dbo.dim_client.*,dbo.dim_transaction.* 
into Allactivity
from dbo.dim_client,dbo.dim_transaction,dbo.fact_capital   
where dbo.dim_client.dim_client_key=dbo.fact_capital.dim_client_key
    and dbo.dim_transaction.dim_transaction_key=dbo.fact_capital.dim_transaction_key
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the select into syntax, you will need to have rights to dynamically create a table.

Another solution is to work with a DBA to create the staging table ahead of time. Then clear and load the staging table each time.  Have the DBA give you or the application rights to the table.  This can be db_datareader & db_datawriter which is a-lot less access than db_owner!

I did notice that you are using older syntax for joins, you should use the newer syntax for forward compatibility.

http://www.straightpathsql.com/archives/2012/11/sql-server-join-syntax-its/

--
--  DBA - Create empty new table (assumes stage schema exists)
--

select
   dc.*,
   dt.*
into 
   stage.all_activity
from 
   dbo.fact_capital as fc 
left join 
   dbo.dim_client as dc 
   on fc.dim_client_key = dc.dim_client_key 
left join 
   dbo.dim_transaction as dt
   on fc.dim_transaction_key = dt.dim_transaction_key
where (1 = 0);

-- User/Application - clear the table
delete from stage.all_activity;

-- User/Application - add some data (+ where clause for range)
insert into 
   stage.all_activity
select
   dc.*, 
   dt.* 
from 
   dbo.fact_capital as fc 
left join 
   dbo.dim_client as dc 
   on fc.dim_client_key = dc.dim_client_key 
left join 
   dbo.dim_transaction as dt
   on fc.dim_transaction_key = dt.dim_transaction_key;